# Разница в датах в одном столбце MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Есть следующие [данные](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/325c1/10/0)

```
id  data
1   01.12.2021
2   03.12.2021
3   05.12.2021
4   12.12.2021
5   15.12.2021
```

Необходимо оставить только те `id` , между которыми не менее 10 дней. То есть на выходе должно остаться

```
id  data
1   01.12.2021
4   12.12.2021
```

Я попробовал через `LAG` и `DateDiff`, но они сравнивают только попарно значения друг за другом. Поэтому между `id3` и `id4` всего 7 дней. И обе строчки убираются. Но между `id1` и `id4` 11 дней и условие выполняется. Но код эту строчку вычеркивает. Подскажите, через какие другие функции можно решить данную задачу ?

Comment: А почему не 2 и 5?

Comment: Изначально считается , что верный по дате `id1` и дальше пляшем от него. Должно пройти минимум 10 дней от последнего "верного"

Comment: Это итеративная задача. Требует рекурсивного CTE либо итеративной хранимой процедуры.

Comment: Можно по-подробнее ?

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT MIN(date0) date0
    FROM test
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t1.date0
    FROM test t1
    JOIN cte ON t1.date0 >= DATEADD(day, 10, cte.date0)
    WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                       FROM test t2
                       WHERE t2.date0 >= DATEADD(day, 10, cte.date0)
                         AND t1.date0 > t2.date0 )
)
SELECT test.* 
FROM test
JOIN cte ON test.date0 = cte.date0;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b1e5a4750662be75eec39aba0134256c)

PS. Решение предполагает, что поле `date0` уникально.

Comment: В примере да, но на реальных данных `date0` не уникально, сможете дать универсальный ответ?

Comment: @CR7 Если это поле - именно дата, и оно неуникально, то я вообще не представляю, как из этой ситуации выкручиваться критериально. Ибо между ними ноль дней, и они автоматически "непоказуемые". Они, конечно, различимы, за счёт уникального `id`, но совершенно несортируемы. В общем, такое дополнительное условие в значительной степени меняет исходную задачу.

Answer (score 0):

Таблица table1 состоит из двух колонок: id, dat (типа DATE)

Такой запрос даст все возможные варианты:

```
select a.id,a.dat,b.id,b.dat from table1 a, table1 b
where DATE_ADD(a.dat, INTERVAL 10 DAY) < b.dat
```

Получим:

```
"1" "2021-12-01"    "4" "2021-12-12"
"1" "2021-12-01"    "5" "2021-12-15"
"2" "2021-12-03"    "5" "2021-12-15"
```

Теперь берем только одну пару дат и формируем результат именно как запрошено:

```
select a.* from table1 a, table1 b 
where date_add(a.dat, INTERVAL 10 DAY) < b.dat limit 1
union all
select d.* from table1 c, table1 d
where date_add(c.dat, INTERVAL 10 DAY) < d.dat limit 2
```

Получаем:

```
"1" "2021-12-01"
"4" "2021-12-12"
```

Comment: И как себя поведёт этот алгоритм на большом наборе данных, в 10-100-1000 и более записей? я уж не говорю о том, что LIMIT без ORDER BY используется исключительно в лототронах.

Comment: Если построен индекс по dat, то должно быть все быстро.